# how to filter by __in for another model objects list

Tags: python, django, filter

hi i want to make a query between two models without having any connection

i want to check if a name in `ModelA` model is in `User`

```
class ModelA(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=20)
    #others
```

how to make a query to filter by all names which already taken in `User` model

i tried these

```
user_name = User.objects.al() 
#and also this
user_name = list(User.objects.all())
#also this 
user_name = User.objects.values()

ModelA.objects.filter(name__in=user_name)
```

i need to return all names which already taken in `User` model!
none of them worked ? is there something else to achieve this goal?
thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to select the `username` values (or some other field) of the `User` model. For example:

```
ModelA.objects.filter(
    name__in=User.objects.values_list('username', flat=True)
)
```

for some databases, like MySQL, it might be better to first materialize the collection of usernames:

```
ModelA.objects.filter(
    name__in=list(User.objects.values_list('username', flat=True))
)
```

If you however want to refer to a record in a table, you better use a [**`ForeignKey`** [Django-doc]](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/fields/#django.db.models.ForeignKey) than a `CharField` that contains the same username.

Or for a `Form`, you can populate this with:

class ClientDailyForm(forms.ModelForm):
customer = forms.ChoiceField(choices=None)

```
def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
    super().__init__(*args, **kwargs)
    usernames = list(User.objects.values_list('username', flat=True))
    self.fields['values'].choices = [
        (c, c)
        Client.objects.filter(
            name__in=usernames
        ).values_list('name', flat=True).distinct()
    ]

class Meta:
    model = InvoiceCustomer
    fields = '__all__'
```

Comment: @art_cs: exactly what is the problem? What values appear in the result that should not or vice versa?

Comment: i just want to return those names who already being used by another model

Comment: @art_cs: yes, but what does it (not) return that is supposed to be in/(out) the queryset? Is there a `ModelA` in the queryset with a name that is not taken, or a `ModelA` not in the queryset that is taken?

Comment: @art_cs: ok, but what does the queryset returns (does not return) that you think it should not (should) return.

Comment: the query you provided return nothing

Comment: @art_cs: are you sure (a) there are `User` objects, and (b) at least one user has the same *username* (so not `first_name`, etc.) that is the same as `name` field (note that whitespaces in front/end means it will not match correctly).

Comment: @art_cs: but this only contains the *models* not data. It is not per se wrong that it returns an empty queryset, that depends on the *data* in the database.